# scikit-learn kmeans custom distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I looking to use the kmeans algorithm to cluster some data, but I would like to use a custom distance function. Is there any way I can change the distance function that is used by scikit-learn?

I would also settle for a different framework / module that would allow exchanging the distance function and can calculate the kmeans in parallel (I would like to speed up the calculation, which is a nice feature from scikit-learn)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You could try spectral clustering algorithm which allows you to input your own distance matrix (calculated as you like).

Its performance has nothing to envy to K-means on convex boundaries, but does also the job on non-convex problems (detects connectivity). See more [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701/slides/Lecture21_2.pdf).

The good news is that spectral clustering is [also implemented in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering).

Hope it helps.